# Issue with NuGet - Cannot download package from nuget in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget

I'm new to Visual Studio 2022 and ASP.NET Core. I have an issue with nuget package. When I'm starting a new project using ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) and Individual Accounts Authentication type. After I created the project, I tried to run (or build it honestly I don't know the differences but I press the green play button anyway) it from the start. It took a long time and then these messages keep appearing in my output tab:

> Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.6.0.21' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/6.0.21/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational.6.0.21.nupkg'.
> The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/6.0.21/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational.6.0.21.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
>
> Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
> Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.6.0.21' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui/6.0.21/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.6.0.21.nupkg'.
> The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui/6.0.21/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.6.0.21.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
>
> Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
> Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.6.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/6.0.1/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.6.0.1.nupkg'.
> The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/6.0.1/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.6.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
>
> Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.

I tried to download them directly from the browser and there are no problem with those url.

Also I tried to create new project with the same setup except I set the authentication type to none and there was no problem at all running it.

Can anyone help me? What did I do wrong?

[image]

this is my folder structure

Comment: Have a look at the steps provided here, to access the package manager, see if it can install from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#find-and-install-a-package

Comment: try to run `dotnet restore` from cmd

Comment: @BernardV still can't download it and gave a same error

Comment: @Den sorry can't resolve with that too :(

Comment: These timeout errors usually touch on a networking issue as opposed to an issue with the project. If you are working on a VPN, you could try running this without the VPN on. If it's some strick work network perhaps ask collueges about this.

Comment: [Try to use microsoft visual studio offline packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20gOi.png), I also faced this issue recently, and this can fixed it. And I agree with BeenardV's comment, it's networks issue.

Comment: Oh yeah you right it was network issue. i change my connection from my office to my home connection and it running no problem at all. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I re-install the latest version of VS2022, and face the same issue. I create a brand new project and still can't restore the nuget packages.

But in my another PC, it works well, so it's hard to say it's network issue or not. Maybe related to the vs2022 version.

But using the Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages can solve the issue.

[image]